# How to call server-side method within client-side method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have an html menu, when one item from it gets clicked I want to call a javascript handler and within it I want to call a server side method, how can I do that?

**I'll talk in details:
I have a file menu, when user click "create directory" -> a java script handler works to add that directory (as a node) to a tree view. 
At the end of the javascript handler I want to call an asp.net method that add that directory to the database.**

**EDIT 2:**
I've tried to use JQuery.ajax() to access the server-side method within the client-side event handler ..this is what my code looks like:

*Controller*

```
   [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult addDirectory(string directoryName)
        {
            Directory dir = new Directory();
          1-  dir.dateCreated = DateTime.Now;
          2-  dir.dateAccessed = DateTime.Now;
          3-  dir.dateModified = DateTime.Now;
          4- dir.ImgURL = "~/Images/Folder-Add-icon.png";
          5-  dir.DirectoryName = directoryName;
          6-  dirRepo.addDirectory(dir);
          7- dirRepo.Save();
            return new JsonResult { Data = dir };

    }
```

*View*

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "Explorer/addDirectory", 
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {param1: name},

          complete: function() {
              alert("finished");
          },

          success: function(data) {
          alert("added");
         },

          error: function() {
          alert("error");
          },
        });
```

The problem is, the "error" method gets called always if I add 1-7 lines in the controller method .. if I comment them out the success method will get called, WHY?

Comment: AJAX.
More details are needed if you want a more detailed answer. For example, what server-side technology you are using. What you want to do on the server-side. Does it update the UI?

Comment: What are you using? ASP.NET MVC? FubuMVC? MonoRail? I assume not WebForms, considering the [mvc] tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controller code

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeMethod(int param1, string param2) {
    return Json(someobject);
}
```

javascript with jQuery

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "controller/somemethod", // or <%=Url helper method can't remember
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {param1: 10, param2: "x"},

  complete: function() {
      //called when complete
  },

  success: function(data) {
      // json returned from server
      //called when successful
 },

  error: function() {
      //called when there is an error
  },
});
```

I suggest googling online for mvc tutorials

Comment: My application can't recognize json .. what should I add?

Comment: Your app can accept json posts, more over it' the recommended way in asp.net mvc, which you say you are using

Comment: Please check the edit up .. I have a problem with your suggested code

Comment: Try sending back a string to begin with, maybe Directory has a problem serializing?

Comment: After debugging I've found out that "directoryName" parameter is passing in as a null value .. !!

Comment: Just changed param1 to directoryName ! everything worked just fined .

Answer (score 0):

To call a server side method on a client side event you need to do the following:

1- Create the server side method:

```
void DoSomething(...) { ... }
```

2- Implement RaisePostBackEvent of the System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler interface which take one string argument (You can use it somehow ..).:

```
public void RaisePostBackEvent(string eventArgument) {
  if (eventArgument == "value") DoSomething(...);
}
```

3- Write a script to trigger post back:

```
function TriggerPostBack(control, arg){ __doPostBack(control, arg); }
```

4- Call the PostBack trigger function when needed:

```
<asp:Button.... onclick="TriggerPostBack('button', 'btnOk')" .. />
```

Comment: Hi Akram. Try to avoid horizontal scrolling in code tags if possible. It just makes posts easier to view. :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a web method

```
[WebMethod]
static string FooBar(string arg) {

}
```

Call WebMethod with ajax. `$.ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest`